# Not able to make two way data binding work on an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I am trying to create kind of a drag and drop playground using AngularJS.
The code is on plunker. And to understand the question, mostly you'll need to see the plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/i82UOOqHRSJyEPN9293E

I am trying to create node like structures here which can be dragged over to the playground on the right side.

On drag, I am adding the node id to the `nodeChain` variable in `$scope`.
Now I am iterating the `nodeChain` array in UI with `ng-repeat` where I am drawing the node just to check that the nodes added to the chain are reflecting correctly.

However,

1. I do not see the `nodeChain` updating from `watchCollection` logs as well as the nodes drawn on the playground are not updating when new nodes are added.

Can someone please tell me why the binding is not taking effect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger a $`digest` cycle to update the values. When the `$digest` cycle starts, it fires each of the watchers. These watchers check if the current value of the scope model is different from last calculated value. If yes, then the corresponding listener function executes. As a result if you have any expressions in the view they will be updated.

```
  if (!Bounds.within(event.pageX, event.pageY, leftPane)) {
                    scope.$parent.nodeChain.push(NodeChain.getNodeFromId(attr.nid))
                    scope.$apply();
            }
```

**Working Plunker**:https://plnkr.co/edit/SNNsVOZps5Fy35dAQIqk?p=preview

You are getting ng-repeat dupes error in your console because there are duplicate values in your array `nodeChain`.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to add the dropped nodes in the below white space. Please see the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/i82UOOqHRSJyEPN9293E?p=preview).

You should add `$scope.apply()` when you change the models outside the scope.